# GoogleMVFaceDetectorResources.bundle/BCLjoy_200.emd is denied

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

After Mac Pro update to version Catalina 10.15.4 I'm getting an error when I'm trying to Debug Xamarin project on iPhone Simulator. I tried to delete bin/obj dirs, clean, rebuild but still the same:

```
  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/testproject.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone 11-13.4/testproject.iOS.app/GoogleMVFaceDetectorResources.bundle/BCLjoy_200.emd" is denied.
```

Comment: Make sure the version of Xamarin.iOS and Xcode are up to date (xamarin.iOS :13.16 Xcode : 11.4.2) .

Comment: Updated and still the same :(

Comment: You could post the error to **Help ->Report  a problem** .